# Jenkins - Move .android folder location

Tags: android, jenkins

When I build project on my local device, the debug key being use is a new one and was located at

`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile`

[image]

I wonder if it is possible to change this reference to what is Android Studio is using which is located at `C:\Users\USER_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you need to set ANDROID_HOME env in jenkins agent settings.
[image]

Comment: For me `ANDROID_HOME` is path for Android SDK